# What is good/free software for monitoring IIS in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, iis, logging, monitoring

I always forget to check what's going on in IIS on our webservers, and am wondering:  is there some stupid applet or something that always runs locally that I can click on to check event logs and IIS logs on a remote machine?

Mark

Comment: you mean "on a remote machine"?

Comment: What are you looking for in the event logs and IIS logs?  The built in Event Viewer in Vista will let you look at a remote server's event logs and filter down to warnings/errors.  For IIS logs, I'd need more information about what you're looking for, e.g. 404/500 events, etc.

Comment: I'm mainly looking for unexpected errors in event log.
It would be nice to have something running in taskbar so i don't have to go through all the clicks of getting to the buildin event viewer and connecting to the right server(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up [samurize](http://www.samurize.com/modules/news/) to follow the output of the logging on the local and remote machines but it requires some setup.

You can use a remote shell utility such as OpenSSH to connect to remote machines securely.

Answer (score 1):

One at a time. Compmgmt.msc -> connect to another computer.

But one at a time is boring. Monitoring dozens of machines? I've been using [logparser from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) for my log monitoring needs. I run a query that dumps errors and warnings to a csv file a few times a day.

So far, I've only used it to aggregate event logs across the dozen servers in our QA environment, but it appears to take many forms on log input, including IIS. A pseudo log file query (don't have samples with me)

```
logparser "Select [eventtype], [message] into output.csv FROM \\server1\system, \\server2\system" -i EVT
```

This shows: You can aggregate multiple servers. You tell it the input format - it supports a dozen log types. You can dump it into a csv file. It looks sort of like SQL.  [This article in security focus](http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1712) has an IIS log sample.

I'm not an applet type of guy, so I haven't though much about desktop widgets to do this.